# como faço para consultar um item do meu banco de dados usando o LIKE + % sendo que a informação está guardada em uma variavel

Tags: python, sqlite3, operador-like

Para exemplificar o que quero fazer:

tenho uma aplicação que armazena id, produtos e quantidades em uma tabela do sqlite3, e quero fazer uma função que busque um produto que o usuário deseja consultar, por exemplo, caso o usuário digite "Banana" eu queria que o programa retornasse todas as Bananas presentes no banco de dados, isto é, gostaria que o programa retornasse por exemplo isso:

Qual produto deseja consultar: Banana

Bananas presentes no estoque
id: 1 | Nome: Banana Prata | Quantidade: 9201
id: 2 | Nome: BANANA Branca | Quantidade: 4234
id: 3 | Nome: banana Terra| Quantidade: 231
id: 4 | Nome: doce de banana | Quantidade: 24234

o meu código até então está assim:

```
for i in self.conexao.execute("select * from produtos where produto like ?", (self.pegar_informacao,)): 
                nova_lista.insert(END, f'Id: {i[0]} | Nome: {i[1]} | Quantidade: {i[2]}')
```

sei que devo usar algo parecido com "select * from produtos where produto like %banana%" porém como disse a informação é passada pelo usuário e é guardada em uma variavel
espero ter sido bem claro, qualquer duvida responda aqui no comentário que eu explico melhor!

Answer (score 0):

para resolver isso eu fiz dessa forma:

```
for i in self.conexao.execute("select * from produtos where produto like ?", ('%'+self.pegar_informacao+'%')): 
                nova_lista.insert(END, f'Id: {i[0]} | Nome: {i[1]} | Quantidade: {i[2]}')
```

neste caso o + junta as strings